# How to import task groups in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-task-groups

I have multiple release pipelines using similar set of tasks. I have created a task group as explained in [Task Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops#help-and-support). I want to reuse this task group in other release pipelines.

I cannot find any task/menu item in Azure DevOps to do so. Documentation in [Task Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops#help-and-support) mentions exporting the release pipeline as json but the import section is not quite illustrative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you created a task group and you want to use it in another releases, just click on the `+` to add a task and in the search field start to type the task group name (for example **TaskGroup1**), then choose it:

[image]

Comment: Problem with this answer is that you put taskgroup1 as the name of the Taskgroup and this causes people to put taskgr in all cases. Please update with a different name for the TaskGroup, for example Mycar.Frontendapp instead of TaskGroup1 in your example.

Comment: For me, the newly added task group didn't appear in the Add tasks window instantly. It was not coming in search results either. After a few minutes it started to appear. It could be a browser cache issue. So the possible options are 1. Restart your browser if that helps clearing the cache when you start the next browser session OR 2. Start your browser in incognito mode as it'll not consider past user sessions OR 3. Wait for a while (~ 5 mins) and then try again to search.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else will have this issue and will come to this thread: even after import and save new task group may not appear under Add task section. In this case try to click Refresh link on the top - it should fetch all changes and update the cached tasks list:
[image]

Comment: I don't see the `Refresh` button in the `Add tasks` section.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and could not find my Task Groups. What fixed it was:

Under Pipelines, go to Task Groups. There you have an Import button where you can import the json Task Group file. When this is done, the Task Group became selectable when wanting to add a new Task.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is not the answer to the question.

Comment: It answers the title of the post. And it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for the name of the Task group in the search box while adding a new task and not "task group".

If you created/imported a task group with name MyCar.FrontendApp, then in the search box for add a new task put "FrontendApp" and add that task.